# Relacionar tablas mysql, qué campos usar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito relacionar una tabla de mysql llamada administradoresRH la cual debe estar relacionada con los registros de otra tabla llamada empleados, y que cada vez que haga una consulta para ver los empleados de un administrador sólo me muestre aquellos que están relacionados con el mismo. Mi problema es que no sé realmente cual de los campos usar para relacionarlos, tengo el id, el dni, el cuit(este ultimo como string, varchar), realmente entré en dudas porque no sé si lo ideal es relacionarlas sólo por id, no se pueden relacinar por el nombre del administrador?? gracias

Acá en la siguiente foto está la tabla administradores, la cual deberia estar ligada a la de empleados, yo pensaba ligarla por nombres de usuario de los administradores pero me tira error, por lo visto sólo puedo hacerlo con números.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá está la tabla empleados la cual al final de tdo le agregué un campo que dici "id_administrador" haciendo referencia al id del administrador de la tabla adminRH.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mostrar en un grafico tu modelo de datos? y de paso especificar un poco mas tus dudas, no se entiende si es sobre el modelo o la query en particular

Comment: Puedes tener dos tablas: `tadministradores` con las columnas `administrador_id, administrador...` y otra tabla `tusuarios` con las columnas `usuario_id, usuario, administrador_id` en ese caso haces la relación por la columna `administrador_id`. **Pero** si un usuario puede tener **varios** administradores, entonces necesitaría una tercera tabla que haga la relación en la cual estarían las columnas `usuario_id` y `administrador_id`.

Comment: No, la idea es que un administrador solo tenga relaccion con un grupo de empleados, pero no varios admin compartan los mismos empleados, estoy recien ahora metiendome con esto de relaciones y creí que era más facil asi que voy a ir despacio. Entonces relaciono las dos tablas con los nombres del administrador? te doy un ejemplo, administrador "Pablo" que tenga los empleados, "pedro, "pepa", y "loza" y otro admin que tenga otros tantos empleados, asi sucesivamente

Comment: Comparte las tablas que mencionas y se puede indicar la relación (si existe conforme lo que compartas); de lo contrario se te puede dar idea (es idea) de que buscar para que lo identifiques, y ya dependera de ti dar con el dato.

Comment: ahi les estoy sacando una foto

Comment: Hazlo por Primary Key. Nunca falla.

Comment: En ese caso sería como te he dicho en el comentario anterior, lo que te digo antes del **pero**. Dos tablas, y en la tabla usuarios tendrías una columna `administrador_id` a través de la cual indicarías quién es el administrador correspondiente a ese usuario.

Comment: ya mismo lo estoy haciendo así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tabla usuarios te falta el id que haga referencia a quien es el administrador de ese usuario.

Mira un ejemplo funcionando. Te toca completarlo, agregar las claves primarias, los índices, etc.

Verás que para las relaciones he usado un campo numérico, que casi siempre es la clave primaria de la tabla administradores, siempre se debe usar un campo que no se repita en dicha tabla, si usas por ejemplo el nombre para relacionar podrías encontrarte con sorpresa, pues puede haber dos administradores que se llamen `Pedro`, en ese caso lo que les diferencia es el `id`, no el nombre.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ee78d/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE administradores
    (`adm_id` int, `adm_nombre` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO administradores
    (`adm_id`, `adm_nombre`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;

CREATE TABLE usuarios
    (`usr_id` int, `usr_nombre` varchar(50), `adm_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO usuarios
    (`usr_id`, `usr_nombre`, `adm_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'usr 1 es de Pedro', 1),
    (2, 'usr 2 es de Pedro', 1),
    (3, 'usr 3 es de Santiago', 2),
    (4, 'usr 4 es de Juan', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT u.usr_id, u.usr_nombre, a.adm_nombre
FROM usuarios u
INNER JOIN administradores a
  ON u.adm_id=a.adm_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ee78d/2/0)**:

```
| usr_id |           usr_nombre | adm_nombre |
|--------|----------------------|------------|
|      1 |    usr 1 es de Pedro |      Pedro |
|      2 |    usr 2 es de Pedro |      Pedro |
|      3 | usr 3 es de Santiago |   Santiago |
|      4 |     usr 4 es de Juan |       Juan |
```

Comment: Gracias chavon, realmente me fue de ayuda, ahora sólo me falta saber como hacer un select de todos aquellos que digan adm:nombre, por eso estoy viendo loq ue hiciste arriba haber si lo entiendo

Comment: Si lo que quieres es todos los usuarios de un administrador en específico basta con modificar la consulta de este modo: `SELECT u.usr_id, u.usr_nombre, a.adm_nombre
FROM usuarios u
INNER JOIN administradores a
  ON u.adm_id=a.adm_id WHERE u.adm_id=1` ahí te dará todos los usuarios de `Pedro`, si quieres filtrar por nombre también puedes, poniendo: `... WHERE a.adm_nombre='Pedro'`, aunque como te decía, conviene filtrar por ids y no por nombres porque hay personas que se llaman igual. El WHERE te sirve para hacer el tipo de filtro que desees.

Comment: Lo hice así y me quedó  perfecto gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para ligar tablas realmente se puede hacer entre cualquier tipo de datos, Ojo se puede esto no quiere decir que se deba, en general cada tabla debe tener una llave primaria la cual se relaciona con otras tablas,

En tu caso lo común es que la tabla de administradores tenga una columna de tipo entero que sea su id, la cual se relacione con los empleados en una columna llama administrador_id

puedes ver mas de normalización en 
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos